# ¿Se pueden comparar variables con tipos de datos?

Tags: c++, variables, condiciones

Soy un programador principiante de c++, y tengo la duda de si hay alguna forma de exigir que se meta el tipo de variable que quiero. Ejemplo: (a == int)

```
int a;

do{
    cout << "Que quieres hacer?" << endl;
    cin >> a;                                               
}while(a == int);
```

Comment: `a` siempre va a ser de tipo `int`, ya que así la has declarado antes. Supongo que lo que quieres es evitar que el programa rompa si el usuario intenta meter otra cosa (por ejemplo "hola"). En ese caso mejor tendrías una variable de tipo cadena para leer lo que el usuario escriba (así no romperá pues en una cadena se puede meter cualquier cosa), para después dentro del programa verificar si la cadena se puede entender como entero o no, para repetir la pregunta en caso contrario.

Comment: Para comprobar los errores de extracción de datos, existe [`std::ios_base::iostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate).

Comment: @abulafia Pero ` a ` después lo uso para un switch, por lo tanto solo acepta variables de tipo ` int `

Comment: @Rubén Ya, quiero decir que tengas otra variable (digamos `a_txt`) que lea la entrada del usuario como cadena, y una función que verifique que esa cadena es numérica y la convierta en `int`, valor que recogerías en `a` para proseguir

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Se pueden comparar variables con tipos de datos?

Si, la cabecera [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) ofrece varias herramientas para trabajar con los tipos de las variables. Por ejemplo, puedes usar [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) para comprobar si el tipo de una variable es igual al tipo de otra:

```
std::cout << std::is_same<int, int>::value << '\n';          // verdadero
std::cout << std::is_same<int, unsigned int>::value << '\n'; // falso
std::cout << std::is_same<int, signed int>::value << '\n';   // verdadero
```

Sin embargo, eso no es lo que quieres hacer, el sistema de tipos de C++ no funciona como crees.

---

C++ es un lenguaje de [tipado fuerte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte), esto significa que las variables tienen un tipo y que este tipo no cambia con el tiempo, así que mirando tu código de *ejemplo*:

```
int a;

do{
    cout << "Que quieres hacer?" << endl;
    cin >> a;                                               
}while(a == int);
```

La variable `a` es y será siempre de tipo `int`, porque así ha sido declarada. Por lo tanto este código generará un bucle infinito:

```
int a;

do{
    cout << "Que quieres hacer?" << endl;
    cin >> a;                                               
}while(std::is_same<decltype(a), int>::value);
```

Lo que en realidad quieres, es comprobar que se ha leído un número. Hacer eso es tan sencillo como verificar que el flujo de consola después de leer un número:

```
int a;

do{
    cout << "Que quieres hacer?" << endl;
    if (cin >> a)
    {
        // Hacer cosas
        cout << "Buen numero!\n";
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Eso no era un numero\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
} while (true);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBPS8QwEMXPyacY62FTUFev21JBELx6X5CYznYH00nNHxSln70mrl0Jgczj/d6EZ6bp2ljNw7JcEhubeoSWXIge9djJf83SSDF0UhJHGDWxquW3FCkQD8B6xDBpgxBi30hRPLqRUvQue4RxKULbQvWcEN4ToccAx2z391XRkXubKUEHUIYYug50nefCiu0WnooVjAs6FOUc95CQgdOI3l3suSoR4jV//K285nzRBlxzztRjcMAO0GtIK77SefuNsai9qs8zDew8ql8jmZdTEe2poUBf2O12o/5U9RVs9ryp/3bP8HEki6CiT1iXLjzG5BluGzkvy6RjPvJO/gA)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

### Comparando tipos

> ¿Se pueden comparar variables con tipos de datos?

Si, puedes obtener el tipo de dato usando `decltype()` y lo comparas usando
`std::is_same`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(a), int>::value << '\n';
}
```

Por ejemplo es código nos imprime `1`, que es verdadero.

### Verificando la entrada del usuario

Pero creo que no es eso lo que tu quieres, parece que quieres verificar que se
haya leído un entero.

#### Lecturas exitosas

En puedes verificar si tu lectura es exitosa de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    if (std::cin>>a) {
        // La lectura salió bien
    } else {
        // La lectura salió mal
    }
}
```

El operador `>>` regresa una referencia al stream, y al colocarlo en un if, se
entiende que queremos hacer una conversión a un booleano. Esta conversión esta
implementada para que regrese verdadero si no hay errores. Si no lo entiendes
ahora no te preocupes, cuando veas overloading de operadores regresas aquí.

#### Como lidiamos con los errores?

Si por algún motivo tu lectura salio mal, tienes que eliminar el flag de error,
y limpiar el stream. Eso se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
    // Le decimos que elimine el flag de error
    std::cin.clear();
    // Ignoramos el resto del stream para hacer una lectura limpia
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

#### Resultado

Podemos juntar estos conocimientos para encontrar una forma segura de leer los
datos:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    // Mientras la lectura falle, limpiamos el stream y pedimos otro.
    while (!(std::cin >> a)) {
        std::cout << "Ingrese un numero porfavor ...\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    std::cout << "Numero ingresado: " << a << '\n';
}
```

### Alternativas

El metodo que te comento @abulafia tambien es perfectamente valido. A mi personalemente no me gusta porque hay que crear un `std::string`, y un `std::stringstream`. Prefiero usar lo justo. Pero la idea de leer un `std::string`, y luego extraer el entero tambien te puede ser util. Tiene como ventaja que no pierdes lo que metio el usuario, y en algun caso algo podras hacer algo con eso. Igual siempre seria un buen ejercicio que tu trates de implementar eso, leelo como texto y validalo.